# Reading .log file using C language in Linux

Tags: c

I have some information in a .log file. Is there any way to read a .log file in C language and convert it to .txt file? Are there any include files or API's I can use?

Comment: Can't you just rename the file, or copy it, to a file with a .txt extension? If you want to process and modify the contents, you would need to decide on what processing you actually want to perform.

Comment: @David Hefffernan I am not allowed to rename the file. Can I change the extension using C code?

Comment: If it's a binary file you need to know how it's formatted, but often log files are just text files with a .log extension.

Comment: If you are not allowed to rename the file, then why ask that question? If you cannot rename the file, then you are not allowed to change the extension.

Comment: The `.log` filename extension has no information about it's contents, besides it is probably used to log some information. How the logging is done is up to the one who wrote it. If you can't read the file, and therefore not copy the file, you can't read it with C either.

Comment: @hetepeperfan I am able to read the file as if it is a text file.

Comment: @Benny In that case, please see the first comment.

Comment: I think you can use a command like "cp" in Linux.

Comment: Unlike in Windows - in UNIX file extensions are only a hint to the user of what could be in a file. They have no function for the OS as such. Although it is good practice to use them for your own convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time a log file is just a formatted text file, so there is no need to convert.

Just use the `rename()` function from stdio.h. Here a reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/.

Comment: Please please please do not link to die.net

Comment: ...? I used it often, but is it out of date or something?

Comment: Yes, it is out of date.

Comment: @david hefferman then what is the latest alternate for rename() ?

Comment: I think he meant the documentation is out of date, not the `rename()` function.

Comment: The Linux docs are at kernel.org

Comment: .. but you are not *allowed* to rename the file!

Comment: Yes, I see that now, but it wasn't in the question. If you may not rename the file, then the question doesn't make sense at all.